# How to create custom (convolution) connection between two different keras layers

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am implementing a custom connection between two different keras layers. The neural network begins something like below:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
c1 = model.add(Conv2D(6, kernel_size=[5,5], strides=(stride,stride), padding="valid", input_shape=(32,32,1), 
                  activation = 'tanh'))
s2 = model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid'))
```

Now, the output of s2 has a size of **14*14*6**

Here, I want to apply my custom connection to convolution layer c3 which has an output size of 10*10*16 (that is, 16 filters need to be applied on s2 of size 14*14*6 and get an output of 10*10*16). For this, I need to use `kernal_size = 5*5`, `filers=16`, `stride = 1`, and `padding=valid`.

However, all the 6 feature maps (of s2) are not connected to 16 feature maps of (c3). The connections are explained as given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCgoa.png).

For example (the explanation of given link above), to build your first feature map of C3, you convolve 3 of your input maps (of s2 of size 14*14*6) with 5x5 filters, which gives you 3 10x10 maps that are summed up to give your first feature map, which is then of size 10x10.

I read somewhere that, we need to use [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) to build this.

But, I am not sure, how to proceed further. Can someone help on implementing this.

My initial approach of implementing this is as follows:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, Concatenate, Lambda, Add

inputTensor = Input(shape=(14, 14,6))
stride =1
group0_a = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,0])(inputTensor)
group0_b = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,1])(inputTensor)
group0_c = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,2])(inputTensor) # Take 0,1,2 feature map of s2

conv_group0_a = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=[5,5], strides=(stride,stride), padding="valid", activation = 'tanh')(group0_a)
conv_group0_b = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=[5,5], strides=(stride,stride), padding="valid", activation = 'tanh')(group0_b)
conv_group0_c = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=[5,5], strides=(stride,stride), padding="valid", activation = 'tanh')(group0_c)  #Applying convolution on each of 0, 1, 2 feature maps of s2 with distinct kernals

added_0 = Add()([conv_group0_a, conv_group0_b, conv_group0_c]) #adding all the three to get one of the 10*10*16

#Repeat this for 16 neurons of c3 and then finally
output_layer = Concatenate()([]) #concatenate them
Mymodel = Model(inputTensor,output_layer)
```

I want to know, if my approach is correct (I know it is not because I am getting too many errors). So, I need help in recreating the custom connection as explained above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems that your code has no problem from your explanation. It just needs to be done over and over again.

Comment: @giser_yugang We need to implement the entire code using Functional API instead of Sequential.

Comment: @VamshiPulluri Did you figure this out? What type of errors are you getting?

Comment: @Moondra Please check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above code  is correct, the only change I made is `group0_a = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,0:1])(inputTensor)`, that is instead of passing `x` as `x[:,:,0]` I passed it as `x[:,:,0:1]`